# UWP respond to Control width change

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want my control to respond to its width change instead of the Window width change. Can I achieve that using `VisualStateManager` or pure xaml?

One possible solution I can think of is using `DataTriggerBehavior`. For example:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Width, ElementName=PlaylistDataTemplateControl}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="1000">
        <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=AlbumTextBlock}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I put it in the `PlaylistDataTemplateControl` but nothing happens when width changes.

Comment: What type of control `PlaylistDataTemplateControl` is? Is it template or any UI Element?

Comment: @GaurangDave It is a `UserControl` in a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I think you should put usercontrol as reference in element name not datatemplate.

Comment: @GaurangDave It is meaningless and I wouldn't reuse it. I make it a control because I want to add VisualStateManager to it. But anyway this should not be helpful for finding a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default trigger for UWP is only about the window. If you want to implement triggering on the control, there are two ways. The first is to listen for the `SizeChanged` event, and the second is to write the trigger yourself.

Here is the first case:

**xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyControl.Background" Value="White"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Width">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MyControl.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <ContentControl x:Name="MyControl" Width="200" Height="100" SizeChanged="MyControl_SizeChanged"/>

    <Button Content="Change Width" x:Name="WidthButton" Click="WidthButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
private void MyControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewSize.Width == 200)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Narrow", true);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Width", true);
    }
}

private void WidthButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyControl.Width = MyControl.Width == 300 ? 200 : 300;
}
```

This is just a simple example. First define the `VisualState` of the control in XAML, then change the state of the control in the `SizeChanged` event, which can achieve your purpose.

If you are interested in custom triggers, you can refer to this [Microsoft-provided example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlStateTriggers), which has a trigger on Control Size.

Best regrads.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I copied the same code from ControlSizeTrigger in the example but I couldn't make it work (I got `System.ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.` at  `_targetElement.SizeChanged += _targetElement_SizeChanged;`). Could you please take a look at my [code](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml)? Trigger is defined [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Triggers/ControlSizeTrigger.cs).

Comment: The reason should be that you are not properly binding the `ContentGrid`. First, separate your UserControl, create a new UserControl control file, and use {x:Bind ContentGrid} to bind it. Second, from your code, you don't need to set two states, set the default value of `AlbumTextBlock` to Collapsed, and then set a MinWidth="1000" trigger to set it to Visible.

Comment: But if I separate them, how is the Music passed to New Control? What I mean is that, how does the new control know it is bound to the data type `Music`?

Comment: like this: `<NewControl DataContext={Binding} />`, In the new control, replace the original `x:Bind` with `Binding`, but for ContentGrid, still use `x:Bind`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. My custom trigger works for a while but now it's not working again. Could you please take a look at my [xaml code](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControlItem.xaml) and [trigger](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Triggers/ControlSizeTrigger.cs)? The parameter in the `SetActive` gives me the expected value, but the `Setters` are not working.

Comment: You can try to modify `TitlePanel.ColumnSpan` to `TitlePanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)`, and the setter that does not work will block the overall configuration from taking effect.